# ValueError("unknown colorspace") while converting tiff to pdf using python img2pdf

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, tiff, img2pdf

I"m getting ValueError("unknown colorspace") when I convert tiff to pdf.

```
>>> import img2pdf
>>> img2pdf.convert(tiff_file_data)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\img2pdf.py", line 1829, in convert
  ) in read_images(rawdata, kwargs["colorspace"], kwargs["first_frame_only"]):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\img2pdf.py", line 1348, in read_images
  imgdata, imgformat, default_dpi, colorspace
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\img2pdf.py", line 1056, in get_imgmetadata
  raise ValueError("unknown colorspace")
```

any way to fix it?
workaround?
or any suggestiong to other python tool I can use to convert?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get a pdf file with manually add colorspace:

```
img2pdf.convert(tiff_file_data, colorspace=img2pdf.Colorspace.CMYK)
```

However, this is not always works perfect and some pages became black.

This is just a workaround so I don't accept this answer, still waiting for better solutions